# Flutter how to work with asynchronous data with Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I have future provider witch loading data from local file. I know, that future provider just can display asynchronous data. How I can modify this data? i mean, i want to added new element into list or delete something from list? how i can do this

```
 FutureProvider(
      create: (context) => MainData().getMainData,
      initialData: MainModel(),
    ),
```

```
  String mainTitle;
  String subTitle;
  List<Notifications> notifications;
  List<Agenda> agenda;

  MainModel(
      { this.mainTitle,
       this.subTitle,
       this.notifications,
      this.agenda});

  factory MainModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MainModelFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MainModelToJson(this);
}
```

```
class MainData{
  Future<MainModel> get getMainData async {
    String localData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/mainPage.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> json = jsonDecode(localData);
    var data = MainModel.fromJson(json);
    /// sor notification's list by order
    data.notifications.sort((a,b)=>a.order.compareTo(b.order));
    /// sor agenda list by order
    data.agenda.sort((a,b)=>a.order.compareTo(b.order));
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe need to use ProxyProvider, but I'm not sure